# Schroedinger equation applicable only in electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

I am new to quantum mechanics - I started reading a book about it one week ago- and I have a question about the Schroedinger equation.

We know that the time-dependent Schroedinger equation has the following form:
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial ψ}{\partial t} = \hat{H}ψ$$
where
$$\hat{H} = -\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x).$$
Is this equation only applicable on electrons or can it be applied to small particles like protons or neutrons? If yes, can it be applied in systems of objects as well just by giving to the $m$ (in the hamiltonian operator) the value of the whole object mass?

Comment: As far as we know, the Schroedinger equation applies to the universe as a whole. The only question is what exactly is $\hat{H}$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of insufficient prior research.

Comment: So what is your asnwer to my question? That we can apply Schroedinger equation in any object, even if it is consisted of multiple particles?

Comment: Yes, the Schrödinger equation is also applicable to multiple particles.

Comment: I'm not sure what to answer because to answer properly I would need to repeat most of what is probably chapters 1 and 2 in whatever textbook you are using. As such I don't think this is a good question for this site. Sean Carroll has a [blog post](https://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2016/08/15/you-should-love-or-at-least-respect-the-schrodinger-equation/) that may help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Schrodinger equation is extremely general, and refers to systems as a whole.

In an elementary introduction to quantum mechanics, you would typically learn how to apply it to systems consisting of a single particle of mass $m$ in an external potential $V(x)$.  However, with appropriate choice of a Hamiltonian you could also apply it to any system you can think of - a single particle fixed in place, several particles which exert forces on one another, a massive system of particles bound together in a lattice, and even [continuous fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory).

All of these different possibilities correspond to different Hilbert spaces and different choices for the Hamiltonian operator.  Some are very simple; for a system with a finite number of allowed energies (like an electron fixed in place immersed in a magnetic field), the Hamiltonian takes the form of a Hermitian $n\times n$ matrix.  Particles which are free to move around have more complex Hamiltonians involving derivative operators (which is the type I assume you have seen already).  Multiple particle Hamiltonians involve [tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) of operators, which is more complicated; this may be explored in a more advanced course, or at the end of a thorough first course.  Quantum field theory is extremely complex and subtle, and is suitable only after a significant amount of preliminary study in non-relativistic quantum mechanics.  My first real exposure to QFT was in graduate school, for instance.

Comment: The Hamiltonian operator that I am used to working with is the $\hat{H} = -\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(x)$. Is this specific expression of the operator applicable to larger objects(let's say a tennis ball) or is it only for the electron?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis Nothing about that expression is specific to an electron. You could insert the mass of the tennis ball if you want. However, it would be a *very* bad model for your average tennis ball, because (1) a tennis ball is made up of many interacting particles, not just one, and (2) it is constantly interacting with its environment via electromagnetic radiation, collisions with air molecules, etc. Neither of these essential features is captured by modeling a tennis ball with that simple Hamiltonian, so you shouldn’t expect any substantial correspondence with real behavior.

Comment: So, since Schoedinger equation applies to bigger objects such as a tennis ball but it gives  bad prediction of their overall behaviour, doesn't that mean that the predictions made by it for even a single particle might be inaccurate?

Comment: @AnastassisKapetanakis You misunderstand me. If you use a Hamiltonian of the form $\hat H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$ to model a tennis ball, you are saying (1) that a tennis ball is a single particle, and (2) that it has no interactions with the surrounding air or electromagnetic field.  Both of those statements are *ludicrously* wrong; a tennis ball is made of $\sim 10^{24}$ particles which interact constantly with each other and with the environment in complicated ways.  So why would you expect such a terrible model to give good predictions?

Comment: Ok, understood! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the equation applies to other particles such as protons etc as well as to collections of particles. Note that to model 2 electrons you can't simply treat them as a single object with twice the mass and charge of an electron- you have to solve a Schrodinger equation that is expressed in terms of their individual positions. The maths gets much trickier as the number of particles to be modelled increases, and you typically have to resort to all sorts of approximations. In my PhD I solved the Schrodinger equation for impurities in metals. It is impossible to do that for a system of trillions of particles without some hugely simplifying assumptions. Typically what you might do to start is to apply the 'one electron approximation' in which you solve the equation for a single electron as if all the other particles in the metal were nailed in place and simply providing a potential that the electron moves in.

Answer (score -2):

I would like to add some information:

The Schrödinger equation describe non-relativistic quantum systems. The problem is that the spin of the electron must be described in relativistic terms. You can describe an electron using the Schrödinger equation but you are ignoring its spin, this is not necessarily a problem to describe processes in which the spin of the electron is irrelevant.

The **Dirac equation** is the relativistic Schrödinger equation that describes spin $\pm 1/2$ particles, that's the case of the electrons. Therefore, in processes where the spin of the electron could be relevant, you must use the Dirac equation.

*Edit:*

Other possibilities to consider the spin in the SE are to add some information about the spin in the Hamiltonian or consider it a-posteriori.

Comment: You don't need a relativistic treatment to describe particles with spin, so this isn't true. Essentially all of solid-state physics uses nonrelativistic quantum mechanics, and spin often plays a very important role there.

Comment: That's true, but... the other possibility is to tell the Schrödinger equation explicitly that the particle has something called spin. An example: let's suppose we are going to describe a crystal with the SE, if you want to take care of spin and see how the band structure has some band degenerations, you must add a relativistic correction in the hamiltonian: the spin-orbit interaction.

Comment: Well yes, of course you need to include information about spin in the Hamiltonian.  But that doesn't mean you need a relativistic treatment or the Dirac equation.  The Schrodinger equation does just fine, and the idea that spin can *only* be described relativistically is a misconception.

Comment: As far as I know, any description of the spin in non-relativistic terms are just approximations of the relativistic case, isn't it? With the edit, I think my answer is correct, or should I delete it?

Comment: The Schroedinger equation is not nonrelativistic.

Comment: Well, *every* non-relativistic description is just an approximation of the relativistic case, since the universe is relativistic as far as we know. But there's nothing *inherently* relativistic about spin.  See e.g. [this blog post](https://quantumchymist.blogspot.com/2014/04/is-spin-relativistic-effect-l-and-first.html), which at a glance seems to describe the situation well.

Comment: @jacob1729 Well, we are talking about the Schrödinger equation that the OP states. That equation is non-relativistic.

Comment: I hadn't noticed OP specified a Hamiltonian. Regardless, 'the SE' is perfectly general, its just the choice of Hamiltonian that specifies if a model is relativistic or not. OP does give a non-relativistic Hamiltonian in the latest post though.